# How to display the userdefined text in label using jQuery in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: jquery

How can I display the userdefined text in a label using jQuery in SharePoint Designer 2013? This is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(readyFn){ 
        function readyFn( jQuery ) {
            $('input[title="Lbl_disp"]').val('Hello');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my label:

```
<td>
    <label id="Lbl_disp"></label>
</td>
```

(Now I want to display the text 'Hello' on the label 'Lbl_disp'). Please help me.

Comment: `$('#Lbl_disp').text('Hello');` and Start learning http://learn.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function){ 

    $("#Lbl_disp").text('Hello');

    }); 
    </script>
```